# How to make the paintComponent method work?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm now studying Head First Java book. And I've encountered an example that shows how to override paintComponent in order to draw a random color circle over black color rectangle having width and height of the whole JPanel.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        int red = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
        int green = (int)(Math.random() * 255);
        int blue = (int)(Math.random() * 255);

        Color randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue);
        g.setColor(randomColor);
        g.fillOval(70, 70, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGui3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But I am not achieving the expected results: nothing is painted on the panel.

**What am I doing wrong? How to make this work?**

Comment: 1) Where do you create an instance of the "MyDrawPanel" class? 2) Where do you add it to the frame? 3) Don't change the state of the component in the painting method. The painting method should only paint the current state. That is don't use "random" logic. You can't control when the component will be repainted. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two additions in main method for this to work. You have to instantiate the MyDrawPanel() class and then add it to the frame.

```
MyDrawPanel p = new MyDrawPanel();
```

and

```
frame.add(p);
```

So the main method should be:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame();
         MyDrawPanel p = new MyDrawPanel();
    
         frame.add(p);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setSize(300, 300);
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```